# Asking a question “did you use to...?” when we don't know whether person still have that habit or not?

Tags: sentence-meaning, habitual-aspect

“used to“ implies habitual actions is the past that is not valid now.
How about questions “did you use to...?”
Could we ask such questions when we want to learn about habits in the past  BUT we aren't sure whether those habits are still valid now or not?

Comment: “The person still has”

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that saying that or asking whether someone "[used to](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/used+to)" do something implies that the action took place in the past and does not still continue.

If you asked me, "Did you used to work with XYZ?" and I still did, my response would say as much: "Yes, and I still do."

If you want to ask without that implication, use  present perfect tense: "Have you worked with XYZ?"

Comment: Did you always conjugated both the auxiliary verb and the main verb? [Did you use to](http://jordanmccollum.com/2013/07/did-use-to-used-to/) is perfectly fine English spelling (although lots of people write *did you used to*.)

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting. I've always seen "used to" as an idiomatic phrase without any conjugation whatsoever (and [I'm not the only one](https://www.englishforums.com/English/DidntUseToVsDidntUsedTo/bwccqk/post.htm)). The written construction is so informal to begin with, and the verbal differences so slight, that this is the first time I've seen anything to the contrary.

Comment: "Did not used to" is the more commonly used construction since 1975, according to [N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=didn%27t+used+to%2Cdidn%27t+use+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15) (and that's just in books). Similarly, "Did you used to" is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Did+you+use+to%2C+Did+you+used+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15) than "Did you use to" (case-sensitive, to avoid constructions like "what did you use to fix it" etc.).

Comment: Okay. I don't have a real objection to the spelling *didn't used to* (although I don't use it). I was mainly objecting to your claim that *didn't used to* was the only way to spell it, which you've now removed from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's also a trick question by implying that a person once did or still does such as "Do you still beat your wife"... the question being that you once did and inferring that you still do. No matter how you answer it with a yes or no. You've just labeled yourself as a wife beater.  The proper question would be; "Have you ever..."

Comment: My example is the following: "Did you use to work with XYZ?"
I want to use "Did you use to ..." to make focus on longer cooperation ( I am not interested in 1 transaction)
Can I ask such question when I don't know if they still work with that supplier?